# Flink produces out file in log folder but does not print anything

Tags: apache-flink

I am using Flink local mode with parallelism = 1.

In my Flink code, I have tried to print the incoming source using:

```
DataStream<String> ds = env.addSource(source);
ds.print();
```

In my local Flink_dir/log folder, i could see that an xxx.out file has been created, but nothing was printed into the file. Is there any config that I might have overlooked? I am sure that my source data contains text as I have managed to add the data to the sink successfully. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ds.print` will write to stdout and not to a file. ${flink_dir}/log contains only the logs of your task and/or job manager.

Comment: Thanks! Just to clarify, where can I see the stdout?

Comment: Depends on where you run it. Local machine?

Comment: Yes, local machine.

Comment: I mean how do you start your application (IDE, commandline, ...)?

Comment: I use command line to start Flink. To run the Flink job, I use the Flink UI on the browser to Submit Job.

Comment: At the flink web UI go to the task manager section and there you should see some kind of tab named stdou (beside configuration and log).